# wysiwyg editor for wordpress is gone

Tags: wordpress

I have something odd going on with our wordpress instance.
We use it for a blog site for content writers that post to it everyday. But for some reason the wysiwyg editor recently just dissapeared? I've tried everything possible but cannot find the fix for this issue.

This is what it currently shows for the editor:
[image]

But this is what it should look like:
[image]

As you can see the "Visual"and "Text" tabs are missing and it seems the editor is stuck in Text mode. I've checked the web console log and can see that the tinymce.min.js script is not even loading at all.

I have a local session running with the exact same source files (only running a different DB) and on my localhost it runs perfectly. So is there a config in the DB that can cause this to happen. I have tried reinstalling source files etc. nothing helps.

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? Try installing the Classic Editor Plugin.

Comment: Do you have a console error?

Comment: @gael there is no console errror either. That is why i think it might be a config issue.

Comment: @Earid we are on the latest version (5.4), I've just tried to use the Classic Editor plugin now. It works 100% on my local, I can activate it on production and see the settings to use the classic or block editor, but the editor does not show at all in the post edit page. I can also confirm there is no errors showing in the console log.

Comment: What type of post are you editing? How did you disable Gutenberg?

Comment: looks like conflict with other plugin, deactivate all plugins, and test one by one.

Comment: @Earid tried that. no luck.